# How to show all the errors and get a JSHint report in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jshint

I have the following code that validates JavaScript code:

```
var jsCode = ".....";  // JavaScript code here
var success = JSHint(jsCode); // 
alert(success); // Shows whether 'true' or 'false'
```

How can I show the list of all errors in the code instead of just 'true' or 'false'? In the documentation, it says, "*In that case, you can use JSHINT.errors to retrieve the errors or request a complete report by calling the JSHINT.data() method.*"

Comment: What is the problem with what the doc says? Once you call `JSHint()`, it retains a reference to the latest analyzed code. Subsequently, calling the `JSHint.data()` method or reading the object from the `JSHint.errors` property will give you all of the data that you need.

Comment: Can you please provide a link, where I can see an example? That will be very helpful.

Comment: What is your setup? What are you trying to build? Given the quotes provided, you are already aware of the JSHint docs. There is not much more needed (not available) other than this. You can fiddle around and test this with your console to figure out the structure of the error objects.

Comment: @MasterAM This is what I am trying to do. Here's a weave. [http://liveweave.com/eBbwxO](http://liveweave.com/eBbwxO)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var jsCode = ".....";  // JavaScript code here
var success = JSHint(jsCode); // 

var data = JSHINT.data();

//Print out list of object props:
for(var i=0; i<data.functions.length; i++){
    for(var j in data.functions[i]){
        document.write(j + ': '+ data.functions[i][j]  +'<br>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Validate Javascript code is a task that need to be automate. To automate task you need to use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

Grunt is an automate task for javascript based projects, then you achieve dependency management, js validate, reports.... etc.

The [grunt-contrib-jshint](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-jshint) plugin could help you.